# Can I add custom JavaScript/jQuery file in React js app?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, themes

I have downloaded a theme(Template) I have add all the required .CSS files in a assets folder in "SRC" and imported them in "index.js" It is working fine!

But now I need to add the template's JS files, (for some events, menu and charts e.t.c).

IS THIS POSSIBLE IN REACT APP?
if yes can you please help me out!

I have tried to add them at the end of body in index.html, also by importing in index.js!!
On importing in index.js it throw bundle of errors.
while on adding in index.html there is no error but it does not working!

Thanks!

Comment: installed jquery from npm i jquery, import $ from jquery, but no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Style Sheets should be add in the public folder.
you can not put them in the src folder.